# Working with Controller.Response and ajax response

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return some error messages in an ajax call but not on error but on success (because the call succeeded and this is just some feedback of things that didn't work).

What code must I write in my controller in order to do something like:

```
success(function (result) 
{
 result.allAccepted...
 result.allRejected...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class as follows:

```
public class JsonResponse
{
    public bool allAccepted { get;set; }
    public bool allRejected { get;set; }
}
```

The above will represent the response you will send back from the controller.

Then create a controller action as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetJson()
{
    var response = new JsonResponse { allAccepted = false, allRejected = true };
    return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This will result in the following json result:

```
{"allAccepted":false,"allRejected":false }
```

This can be parsed as you describe.

Comment: I take it I can't add info to `result` using `Controller.Response`?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu I wouldn't, I'd use the above. I've never known anyone or read anything about setting a response in that way.

Comment: well my method returns void so I wanted to use `Response` instead of `return`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetJson()
{
    return Json(new string[] { "allAcceptedValue", "allRejectedValue" }, 
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**or**

```
 return Json(new   {
                     allAccepted= yourdata,
                     allRejected= yourdata,
                   }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

//Get Data in Jquery

```
    var obj = $.stringify(data);
    var allAcceptedValue = obj[0];
    var allRejectedValue = obj[1];
```

**or**

```
    var obj = $.stringify(data);
    var allAcceptedValue = obj.allAccepted;
    var allRejectedValue = obj.allRejected;
```

Comment: there is no need for `stringify`